# Why does S-param resonance behavior differ from formula?

Tags: resonance

The general formula for resonance is \$w_0=\frac{1}{LC}\$  . A simulation was built with such inductor and capacitor so the resonance will be at 1GHZ.However as you can see in the result ,the plot shows  a very small Q factor resonance and its resonating not at a frequency which differs the formula. Where did i go wrong?

$$
w_0=\frac{1}{LC}=1 GHz
$$

[image: ADS ADS schematics]

[image: ADS plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, notice that the impedance of your circuit is given by:

$$\left|\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|\left(\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{C}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{L}}\right)^2}}\tag1$$

Now, we can see that \$\$ is at a maximum when:

$$\omega\text{C}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{L}}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega:=\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\tag2$$

Which gives:

$$\left|\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|\left(\hat{\omega}\right)=\text{R}\tag3$$

So, now we can solve for the cut-off frequencies:

$$\left|\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|\left(\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega:=\omega_\pm=\frac{\displaystyle1\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{\displaystyle4\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}}}{\displaystyle2\text{CR}}\tag4$$

So, for the bandwidth we get:

$$\mathcal{B}:=\left|\omega_+-\omega_-\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\sqrt{1+\frac{\displaystyle4\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle\text{L}}}\tag5$$

And for the quality factor we get:

$$\mathcal{Q}:=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\omega}}{\displaystyle\mathcal{B}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\sqrt{1+\frac{\displaystyle4\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle\text{L}}}}=\text{R}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{L}+4\text{CR}^2}}\tag6$$

Using your values, we get:

$$\mathcal{Q}=50\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle10^{-9}}{\displaystyle10^{-9}+4\cdot10^{-9}\cdot50^2}}=\frac{\displaystyle50}{\displaystyle\sqrt{10001}}\approx0.499975\tag7$$

Comment: Hello, I am new to this forum.what is the proper way to put photos in the responces?
Thanks.

Comment: @Josh23, AFAIK images can't be used in comments. If you need an image to make your point you could either give a link to an image on another site (an image-sharing site); or if it's appropriate, edit your question post to include the image.

Answer (score 3):

> *Why does S-param resonance behavior differ from formula?*

Because you have not used the correct formula. You stated this: -

> *\$w0=\dfrac{1}{LC}=1GHz\$*

A more suitable formula is this (note the square root of L and C): -

$$\omega_0=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

If you enter the values of 1 nF & 1 nH you get a natural resonant frequency of 159.15 MHz. The above formula yields radians per second and, to get hertz, you must divide by \$2\pi\$.

Answer (score 2):

For the frequency -

The formula you quote gives you the radian frequency. 1 Grad/s = 1G/2pi Hz, roughly the 150 to 160 MHz we can read off the graph.

For the Q -

The inductor has a resistance of 1 ohm. This is probably a default the simulator assigned. As its reactive impedance is only 1 j.ohm at the resonant frequency, the Q will be in the order of 1.

Hint, if you do increase the Q by decreasing that inductor resistance, or increasing the inductance, you will need to improve the frequency resolution around the resonant frequency to be able to see a sharp dip in the S11.

Should you set the inductor resistance to 0 and get an infinite Q, think about what S11 you would expect with the port seeing an effective open circuit at resonance.

Comment: I'm not sure if usage is different in the UK, but in the US, "grad" is used to refer to 1/400 of a unit circle, not 1 radian. I believe this is actually a holdover from French practice --- the only place I've seen it used is in the manuals of certain calculators that allow selecting between degrees, radians, and grads for angle measures.